# post-receive hook generating 'no such file or directory' error

Tags: git, git-post-receive

I am attempting to set up a post-receive hook for a production website. The code seems to partially work, but the files are not copied.  In this directory I have set up a bare repository:

```
public_html/deploy-dir
```

In hooks/post-receive there is the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# post-receive

# 1. Read STDIN (Format: "from_commit to_commit branch_name")
from, to, branch = ARGF.read.split " "

# 2. Only deploy if master branch was pushed
if (branch =~ /master$/) == nil
    puts "Received branch #{branch}, not deploying."
    exit
end

# 3. Copy files to deploy directory
deploy_to_dir = File.expand_path('../')
`GIT_WORK_TREE="#{deploy_to_dir}" git checkout -f master`
puts "DEPLOY: master(#{to}) copied to '#{deploy_to_dir}'"
```

The remote url is something like this:

```
ssh://username@thesite.org/home/username/public_html/deploy-dir
```

When executing 'git push production master' I get the following output in the terminal:

```
Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 300 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: /usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
To ssh://username@thesite.org/home/username/public_html/deploy-dir
    3a5ab4d..6c49ce0  master -> master
```

I believe the 'no such file or directory' error has something to do with line 1 of the post-receive hook.  Something is missing there, and I don't know what it should be.  This post-receive code works on another server.

Or, possibly my deploy-to-dir path is not correct?  Should it be:

```
deploy_to_dir = File.expand_path('../')
```

or

```
deploy_to_dir = File.expand_path('..')
```

Comment: What is the path to `ruby` on the remote server?

Comment: Ruby is not installed I believe --  ruby -v outputs 'ruby: command not found'  I submitted a support ticket to the hosting provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you indicated in your comment, the output from `env` indicates that `ruby` is not available in the PATH on the remote side.

You have `git`, which means you have `perl`. Would you consider the following?

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
# post-receive

use warnings;
use strict;

use Cwd 'abs_path';

# 1. Read STDIN (Format: "from_commit to_commit branch_name")
my($from,$to,$branch) = split " ", scalar <STDIN>;

# 2. Only deploy if master branch was pushed
if ($branch ne "master") {
    warn "Received branch $branch, not deploying.\n";
    exit 0;
}

# 3. Copy files to deploy directory
my $deploy_to_dir = abs_path('../');
$ENV{GIT_WORK_TREE} = $deploy_to_dir;
if (system("git checkout -f master") == 0) {
    print "DEPLOY: master($to) copied to '$deploy_to_dir'\n";
}
else {
    warn "DEPLOY: checkout failed\n";
    exit 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was a simple matter of ruby not being installed on the server.  Support installed ruby and issue resolved.